# Storing multiple types in map

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, std

I want to store multiple type of objects in a map, and I came up with this solution. I must know the type of each object, so I can't use **boost::any**. Is there a better way to do this, or this is an acceptable solution?

```
enum eType
{
    TYPE_STRING,
    TYPE_NUMBER,
};

class CType
{ 
public:
    int GetType() { return m_Type; }

protected:
    int m_Type;
};

template <typename T>
class CData : public CType
{
public:
    CData(const T & rData, int iType)
    {
        m_Type  = iType;
        m_Data  = rData;
    }

    T & GetData() { return m_Data; }

private:
    T m_Data;
};

std::map<unsigned long, CType *> map_Data;

void main()
{
    // Create a new data with TYPE_NUMBER
    CData<short> data(32767, TYPE_NUMBER);

    // Add it to the map
    map_Data[0] = &data;

    // Get the type
    switch (map_Data[0]->GetType())
    {
        case TYPE_NUMBER:
        {
            // Cast the first element to CData
            CData<short> * pField = (CData<short> *)map_Data[0];

            // Print the data
            printf("Data: %d\n", pField->GetData());
        }
        break;

        case TYPE_STRING:
        {
            // Cast the first element to CData
            CData<std::string> * pField = (CData<std::string> *)map_Data[0];

            // Print the data
            printf("Data: %s\n", pField->GetData().c_str());
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to run it? also `void main` does not exist

Comment: Sure I tried, it works in visual studio.

Comment: You're asking for an opinion.  If you ran it, the compiler accepted it.  Is that good enough?

Comment: See this question also [creating-an-interface-for-an-abstract-class-template-in-c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251549)

Answer (score 1):

Use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) and [boost::any_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/any_cast_idp6057536.html).

A check to see if the any is an int;

```
bool is_int(const boost::any & operand)
{
    return operand.type() == typeid(int);
}
```

A check to see if the any is a `const char *`

```
bool is_char_ptr(const boost::any & operand)
{
    try
    {
        any_cast<const char *>(operand);
        return true;
    }
    catch(const boost::bad_any_cast &)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pollute your classes with functions like `getType`, a basic and easy to use solution is using a tagged union like the one in the following example:

```
#include <map>

struct StructA { };
struct StructB { };

struct TaggedUnion {
    enum { A, B } tag;
    union {
        StructA a;
        StructB b;
    };
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::size_t, TaggedUnion> map;
    map[0] = TaggedUnion{ TaggedUnion::A, StructA{} };

    switch(map[0].tag) {
    case TaggedUnion::A:
        // do whatever you want with map[0].a;
        // ...
        break;
    case TaggedUnion::B:
        // do whatever you want with map[0].b
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is interesting and I do not understand why so downvoted. Unfortunately what you are trying to do is impossible in C++ ( I wonder if it is feasible in Java or C# )

I put again the link of what I think is the core of your question.

[creating-an-interface-for-an-abstract-class-template-in-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251549/)

Out of this your implementation is interesting. I just put some rework here as I think you can spare some lines without nasty switch case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <List>

using namespace std;

struct CType
{
    int GetType() { return m_Type; }
    string GetStringVal() { return m_string_val; }
    enum eType {     TYPE_STRING,
                     TYPE_NUMBER };
protected:
    int m_Type;
    string m_string_val;
};

template <typename T>
class CData : public CType
{
public:
    CData(const T & rData):m_Data(rData)
    {
        stringstream strs;
        m_Type  = GetType();
        //Mingw bug
        //m_string_val = std::to_string(m_Data); //c++11
        strs << m_Data;
        m_string_val = strs.str();
    }

    T & GetData() { return m_Data; }

private:
    T m_Data;
    CType::eType GetType();
};

template<> CType::eType CData<int>::GetType() { return TYPE_NUMBER; };
template<> CType::eType CData<string>::GetType() { return TYPE_STRING; };
//More specialization here

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    CData<int> cd_int(5);
    CData<string> cd_str("SO contribution");

    list<CType> my_list = { cd_int, cd_str };

    for ( auto & elem : my_list)
        cout << elem.GetStringVal() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results are naturally:

Hello world!

5

SO contribution

-----**ADD-ON** 2016-Sept-05-----

Another possibility is to store a function ( lambda with "this" capture ) returning the result instead of the result itself. It avoids to perform updates when the m_Data field changes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <List>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct CType
{
    int GetType() { return m_Type; }
    string GetStringVal() { return m_string_func(); }
    enum eType {     TYPE_STRING,
                     TYPE_NUMBER };
protected:
    int m_Type;
    function<string()> m_string_func ;
};

template <typename T>
class CData : public CType
{
    public:
    CData(const T & rData):m_Data(rData)
    {
        m_Type  = GetType();
        m_string_func = [this](){   //MinGW bug,otherwise to_string()
                                    stringstream strs;
                                    strs << m_Data;
                                    return strs.str();};
    }

private:
    T m_Data;
    CType::eType GetType();
};

template<> CType::eType CData<int>::GetType() { return TYPE_NUMBER; };
template<> CType::eType CData<string>::GetType() { return TYPE_STRING; };

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    CData<int> cd_int(5);
    CData<string> cd_str("SO contribution");

    list<CType> my_list = { cd_int, cd_str };

    for ( auto & elem : my_list)
        cout << elem.GetStringVal() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```