# Wrap different std::vector<T> in same interface

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have 2 classes for managing 2 queues of different types (something in the form of `list<myType1*>` and `list<myType1*>`).
To simplify the case, we can use here `std::vector<std::string>` and `std::vector<int>` as in the example below:

```
class StringQueue
{

public:
    StringQueue();
    ~StringQueue();

    int count() const {return m_queue.size();}
    void add(std::string item) {m_queue.push_back(item);}
    void clear() {m_queue.clear();}
    ...etc...

protected:
    std::vector<std::string> m_queue;
};

class IntQueue
{

public:
    IntQueue();
    ~IntQueue();

    int count() const {return m_queue.size();}
    void add(int item) {m_queue.push_back(item);}
    void clear() {m_queue.clear();}
    ...etc...

protected:
    std::vector<int> m_queue;
};
```

For every `Queue` class, I have many functions to access the queue (add, clear, count, check, pop one, pop multiple, etc...)

Looking at the code, my question now is: is it possible to use inheritance here?
I know I can implement a `Queue` base class, but only a couple of functions can be derived (`count()` in the example above) since the m_queue object is different, even if the functions (`add`, `clear`, etc...) are the same.
Is it possible to have a complete functions inheritance even if the `std::vector` elements are different?

I'm thinking something like:

```
class Queue
{

public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();

    int count() const {return m_queue.size();}
    void add(T item) {m_queue.push_back(item);}
    void clear() {m_queue.clear();}
    ...etc...

protected:
    std::vector<T> m_queue;
};
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can somebody be so kind to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Inheriting standard container classes is a very bad idea. Use them as member variables instead.

Comment: As it seems the OP is interested in templatizing the class. It seems the title is just wrong/misleading.

Comment: @ben I commented? What's your concern?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No concern. Your comment could be interpreted as an answer to the question before...

Comment: Should rather be closed as a duplicate to this, imo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3251549/1025391

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes, a template version might help in reducing to write boiler plate stuff.

Comment: I think the question is not a duplicate. I don't want to inherit from containers. I would like to use containers for managing 2 queues of different types. I don't need the standard container methods interface

Comment: @moooeeeep Added.

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use template version of the class!! is there any good reason for avoiding that?

Comment: Have a look at any std::stack or std::priority_queue implementation. It's a container wrapper like the one you want. Also, NEVER inherit from any STL container.

Comment: @ABCplus Just write a templated version of your Queue then.

Comment: If you don't want to inherit from containers, what did you expect people to understand by "Inherit from a std::vector"?

Comment: Never inherit from `std::vector`. Its destructor is not virtual

Comment: @Useless you're right. Title edited by somebody more expert than me

Comment: @moooeeeep: I don't know how to do it

Comment: @Ayxan Polymorphism is not the only purpose of inheritance. It's perfectly fine to inherit from a non-virtual base, just you then cannot use such a class polymorphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect job for templates:

```
template<class T>
class MyQueue
{
public:
    MyQueue();
    ~MyQueue();

    int count() const {return m_queue.size();}
    void add(T item) {m_queue.push_back(item);}
    void clear() {m_queue.clear();}
    T popOne()
    {
      T front = m_queue.front();
      m_queue.erase(m_queue.begin());
      return front;
    }
    ...etc...

protected:
    std::vector<T> m_queue;
};
```

Inheritance is not the right tool for the job, for the reasons you identified yourself.

However:

1. Why don't you use `std::queue` and friends, which already do exactly this wrapping?
2. Why do you want to build a queue based on `std::vector` - erasing elements from the front involves moving *every* other element one slot forward. That's about as expensive as it gets...

I recommend you read up more on templates if you want to use them further. While the above code looks nice and easy, writing templated code in C++ has its own set of challenges.